# Order of operations in LATERAL join?

Tags: performance, join, postgresql-10, query-performance

Consider the following query to find the (spatial) nearest neighbor; the PostGIS specific components here should not be of importance for my question, or so I believe:

```
SELECT a.id,
       c.geom
FROM   table_a AS a
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT ST_MakeLine(a.geom, b.geom) AS geom
  FROM   table_b AS b
  ORDER BY
         a.geom <-> b.geom
  LIMIT  1
) AS c;
```

(`<->` is a PostGIS specific distance operator optimized to use the (spatial) index when in `ORDER BY`)

I assume the the `ST_MakeLine` function executes once, after the `LIMIT 1` filter has been applied, but **I'd like to verify if I'm correct and/or what's the actual order of operations here?**

I thought I have a profound idea of the core operation chain, but I fail to grasp if it would, in fact, be beneficial to move possibly costly functions, involving the reference value and its one nearest neighbor, into the outer (left hand) `SELECT`.

---

**UPDATE:**

So I did as suggested and benchmarked performance and function execution with a custom function wrapper:

```
SELECT a.id,
       c.geom
FROM   table_a AS a
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT wrapper_function(a.geom, b.geom) AS geom
  FROM   table_b AS b
  ORDER BY
         a.geom <-> b.geom
  LIMIT  1
) AS c;
```

and

```
SELECT a.id,
       wrapper_function(a.geom, c.geom) AS geom
FROM   table_a AS a
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT geom
  FROM   table_b AS b
  ORDER BY
         a.geom <-> b.geom
  LIMIT  1
) AS c;
```

produce the same query plan, and execute `wrapper_function` for every row in `table_a`. I expected that.

However, a minor thing I found was that after multiple benchmarks with 1000 runs on equal setups, the first syntax performed about 1% better than the second, on different table sizes. I cannot be sure, but the query planning time seems higher on the last query.

Still interested in the exact order of operations, and maybe to find out what could make the difference (random vs. reason)?

Comment: Try to test... create your own function defined as deterministic which calculates and returns `ST_MakeLine(argument1, argument2)` and additionally saves/counts arguments into some service table.

Comment: @Akina ...you got me there, I use to give that same advice on questions; I would still like to know the exact order of operations. should I rephrase, would you deem this question silly in any way?

Comment: I updated with the worded result of my benchmarking.